# Distributed union not working as expected on recursive type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a recursive type that treats unions of strings in a non distributed fashion, as per https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types.

```js
type TRecursiveType<T> = 
    T extends Record<string, unknown>
    ? {
        [K in keyof T]: TRecursiveType<T[K]>
    }
    : [T] extends [string]
    ? Array<T>
    : never;

type TExample = {
    frodo: "baggins" | "underhill",
};

type TResult1 = TRecursiveType<TExample>;
```

In the example above, `TResult1` comes out as:

```js
type TResult1 = {
    frodo: "baggins"[] | "underhill"[];
}
```

However I was expecting it to be:

```js
type TResult1 = {
    frodo: ("baggins" | "underhill")[];
}
```

Why isn't the non-distributive behaviour of `[T] extends [string]` taking effect?

Comment: You also need to prevent distribution in the first conditional: https://tsplay.dev/w8XV0w
In distributive conditionals, both the "true" and "false" clause get the distributed type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to wrap both sides of the first extends with square brackets like so:

```js
type TRecursiveType<T> = 
    [T] extends [Record<string, unknown>]
    ? {
        [K in keyof T]: TRecursiveType<T[K]>
    }
    : [T] extends [string]
    ? Array<T>
    : never;
```